# Wix: Show conditional message box without cancel

Tags: wix

is there some way to show a message box due to some condition but **continue** installation?

I would like to inform the user about the recommended amount of RAM if he has less.

If I use

```
<Condition Message="For running $(var.ProductName), 4GB of physical memory are recommended.">
    <![CDATA[PhysicalMemory > 3500]]>
</Condition>
```

the installation is unsuccessful on machines with less than 4GB of RAM.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to Cosmin Pirvu's answer I found the following solution with `custom actions` to work for me, I want to share with you:

```
<Custom Action="PhysicalMemoryWarning" After="InstallInitialize" />
<CustomAction Id="PhysicalMemoryWarning" Script="vbscript">
  <![CDATA[
  If session.Property("PhysicalMemory") < 3500 Then
    MsgBox("For running $(var.ProductName), 4GB of physical memory are recommended.")
  End If
  ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Comment: It would be good to also use session.Message - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371672(v=vs.85).aspx - instead of MsgBox. This will help keep window parenting and focus correct.

Comment: Many thanks for your hint! Under Win7 we frequently ran into the problem that the MsgBox appeared "behind" the actual installer window. If I understand you correctly, this might be fixed by using `session.Message`? (I have to admit that I still do not completely understand the documentation you linked to :? )

Comment: Right, if you use session.Message, it'll be parented correctly so that it won't go behind the main MSI window. The VB API I linked to is just a wrapper around MsiProcessMessage - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370354(v=vs.85).aspx - and its See Also link is useful - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371614(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer doesn't offer direct support for this. But you can use a simple [custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm). It can be an EXE, DLL, VBScript, JavaScript etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have added an answer containing the custom action solving my problem.